# Getting result even null on field

Tags: mysql

I had a query like this :

```
SELECT * FROM customer AS c, customer_group AS cg 
WHERE c.customer_id = '10002' AND c.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id
```

When the 'customer_group_id' field was NULL for that ID (10002) on database, it won't show. Please help me to correct this query. And if 'customer_group_id' field was not NULL for that ID, it will show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a left join:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer AS c
LEFT JOIN customer_group AS cg
    ON c.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id
WHERE c.customer_id = '10002'
```

The syntax you are using to join the tables (which was superseded nearly 20 years ago) is effectively an INNER JOIN, which *requires* there to be a joined row for the row in the first table to be returned.

A LEFT JOIN will always return rows from the first table, but if there isn't a joined row, nulls will be in the joined table's columns.

Comment: Can you explain what's the problem with my query and why it should use join?

Comment: [This](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) might help to demystify join types

Comment: @AldryWijaya explanation added. You should *never* join tables like you have. That was replaced in the SQL standard in 1996 by the JOIN keyword.

Comment: Thanks for both of you. I never noticed this problem before.